# adding win32 app icon to task bar

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to add some simple win32 application's icon to task bar while app is running in background. During this time, i want to send some msgs to that icon so that it pops up as per my req. Unfortunately i know only c\c++ and i use visual studio8, is there a way or api to do this? 
example: outlook icon or wifi icon

Comment: I got it clearly, thanks nick & madsen. +1 to you both.

Comment: You mean: Notification area (i.e. System tray) in the taskbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure there is an api, [Shell_NotifyIcon function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159%28VS.85%29.aspx) does that.

You have to fill a [NOTIFYICONDATA Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773352%28VS.85%29.aspx) and then call the above function.
What `Shell_NotifyIcon` will do depends on the flag that you'll set.

Answer (score 2):

Are you after a way to just show an icon down there, or do you want pop-ups like those Outlook and the like show when something happens?

To manipulate the icon itself, use Shell_NotifyIcon. There's a description of all of these things in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330740(VS.85).aspx). IF you want to show a pop-up, then you'll need to either use the balloon pop-ups (see the article), or create your own window and manage it yourself. It's up to you to determine which one is more appropriate for your needs.